# Java: Invalid thread access

Tags: java, multithreading, swt

I am java noob programmer and I have got problem with SWT Exception Invalid thread access, I have look for that and I have found that *It happens when you try to act upon an interface item from a thread that's not the UI thread.* but I don't know how to fix it.

**Problem:**
I have got 4 classes:

- notify - create swt window that shows notify
- main thread - download content from the net and using notify class shows notifications
- Window - it shows tray icon, settings and it is main class - it start main thread
- class that shows notifications in second swt window.

Problem is that it crash with Invalid thread access. I have no idea how to **show two swt windows (completely different classes)**

---

That application downloads webpage, parse it and get information I want. Then using class *notify* it shows notification. I added class *Window* that is SWT Window and it shows tray icon, there are settings it also is main class and that class run *ZadaneReader* thread. **First question:** should I add SWT window (main goal of that is: tray icon and settings) in other way?

My application contains following classes:

- ZadaneReader - it downloads webpage, parse it and with class *Notify*, it shows notification
- Notify - that class shows notifiations with 2 ways:
  a) using exec *notify-send* (but it is Ubuntu only in that way) and b) it create object UniNotifyWindow that is second SWT window that shows notifications
- UniNotifyWindow - swt window that shows its own notification
- Window - settings, tray icon, **main class at the moment** it start its thread and ZadaneReader thread

At the moment: it works when I am not using UniNotifyWindow **or** I am not using Window (start Zadane thread with tester class).

I suppose it is noobish question and I have made many mistakes, but I wish you won't blame me but I would be pleased if you could tell me what I am doing wrong.

**Source:** https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B5VL4J_7HrgaTkt4a1Q2VVQxZEE

Comment: can you provide a small and cleaned example? Do you know about keywords like event dispatch thread: [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) and/or [SwingUtilities.invokeLater](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater(java.lang.Runnable) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may only access SWT UI elements from the main (aka "display") thread. This means that you can't do as much as set text in a text box from another thread. The easiest way to push work to display thread is by calling

```
Display.getDefault().asyncExec(...)
```

Be warned that you should be discrete in what you run in your display thread - long-running tasks will make your UI unresponsive.